# Putting jailbreak app on iPod Touch (works but no data)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, jailbreak

Hi
I jailbreak my my ipod 4g and build my app. Then I installed openSSH and using cyberduck put my app in applications folder and changed the permissions to 777. My app works but it doesn't load images and data(from plist). It basically empty, all I see is a tab bar, and view controllers, everything else is empty...
What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: If you run it from a terminal, do you get anything to stdout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What method do you use to load your Data?..
Be sure to use `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyDataFile" ofType:@"plist"]`

When you rely on the NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains-technique you might get some different path in a jailbroken environment (/var/mobile/Documents instead of /var/mobile/Applications/SOME-GUID/Documents)